# Missing background image setting in admin of twenty nineteen

Tags: images, wp-admin

I have installed fresh Wordpress 5.0 with twenty nineteen theme. In admin panel for home page below colors setting a link to setting background image should be visible. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zxAMjGC4z08 (41th second).

[image: screenshot from my Wordpress]

What is wrong with my Wordpress?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's not present because it's not supposed to be present, it was removed.**

While originally added to the theme, it was deliberately removed due to accessibility concerns, see https://github.com/WordPress/twentynineteen/issues/708 which is the same question but on GitHub

Keep in mind that the video you linked to is not the final version of the theme, but a WIP version mid-development prior to its final release

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong. This option doesn't exist in Twenty Nineteen. The video you've linked is from 2 months before its release, and doesn't represent the final product.